How to prove that trivial representation is a subrepresentation of any permutation representation?
First, assume that

...$K$ denotes a field of arbitrary characteristic, $G$ a finite group and all $K$-vector spaces are finite-dimensional.

Then, the elementary exercise asks the reader to:

Prove that the trivial representation of group $G$ is a subrepresentation of any permutation representation of $G$ over $K$.


Since the exercise refers to "the trivial representation", and not just "a trivial representation", one must conclude that $V = K$ (see the definitions below).
Now, if $X$ is a $G$-set, and $\rho_X: G \to GL(V) = GL(K)$ is a permutation representation of $G$ associated with $X$, then $X$ must be a singleton, since $|X| = \mathrm{dim}_K(V) = \mathrm{dim}_K(K) = 1$.  I conclude that the trivial representation must be identical to any "permutation representation of $G$ over $K$".  This is clearly a much stronger conclusion than what the exercise is asking one to prove.
I feel I must be missing something.

Here are the definitions I am working with.

A $K$-representation of $G$ (or a (linear) representation of $G$ (over $K$)) is a group homomorphism
$$\rho : G \to GL(V),$$
where $V$ is a $K$-vector space of dimension $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$.
If $G$ is an arbitrary ﬁnite group and $V := K$, then
$$\rho : G \to GL(K) \cong K^{\times},\;\;\; g \mapsto \rho(g) := \mathrm{Id}_K \leftrightarrow 1_K$$
is a $K$-representation of $G$ called the trivial representation of $G$.
Similarly, $\rho: G \to GL(V), g \mapsto \mathrm{Id}_V$, with $\mathrm{dim}_K(V) =: n > 1$ is also a $K$-representation of $G$ and is called a trivial representation of $G$ of degree $n$.
If $X$ is a ﬁnite $G$-set, i.e. a ﬁnite set endowed with a left action $\cdot : G\times X \to X$, and $V$ is a $K$-vector space with basis $\{e_x \;|\; x \in X\}$, then $$\rho_X: G \to GL(V),\;\;\;\;g\mapsto \rho_X(g):V\to V, e_x\mapsto e_{g\,\cdot\,x}$$ is a $K$-representation of $G$, called the permutation representation associated with $X$.
Let $\rho: G \to GL(V)$ be a $K$-representation of $G$.
[Then, a] subspace $W \subseteq V$ is called $G$-invariant if $$\rho(g)(W) \subseteq W\;\;\;\;\forall g\in G.$$
If $\rho: G \to GL(V)$ be a $K$-representation and $0 \neq W \subseteq V$ is a $G$-invariant subspace, then $$\rho_W : G \to GL(W),\;\;\;\;g \mapsto \rho_W(g):= \rho(g)|_W:W \to W$$ is called a subrepresentation of $\rho$.


TLDR please try restating this more concisely in order to improve your chances of getting a response

For your recent question (which you have deleted), see for example here. It has been asked many times, it seems.

@DietrichBurde: Thank you.  Also, I apologize for my ill-mannered comment earlier.

No problem ......... :)


Since the exercise refers to "the trivial representation", and not just "a trivial representation", one must conclude that $V = K$ (see the definitions below).

This is not the intended interpretation. The use of the phrase "the trivial representation" here signifies that we are talking about a unique isomorphism class of representations (namely the unique isomorphism class of $1$-dimensional representations on which $G$ acts trivially). To say that "the trivial representation is a subrepresentation of $V$" is, if you like, shorthand for:

the trivial representation is isomorphic to a subrepresentation of $V$.

(This is the typical meaning of "a subrepresentation of" in general.)
So, the intended exercise is to prove that if $V$ is a permutation representation then there exists a $1$-dimensional subspace of $V$ on which $G$ acts trivially. Can you solve it now?

Thank you.  I suppose that a permutation representation would act trivially on the vector space generated by the vector $\sum_{x\in X} e_x$, but I think I still need to think about it some more before I can say I can "solve it now."  At any rate, thank you again for the clue.

@kjo: yes, that's how the argument goes.
